# Can I load a notebook without evaluating it?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I have a long notebook with a lot of definitions, calculations, etc. If I want to open the notebook on a new computer, or even on my computer after it has been shut down; then in order to make use of all the previous calculations and definitions I need to evaluate the notebook. However, given the size of the notebook, and the complexity of some of the calculations, it will usually take mathematica a long time to evaluate the entire notebook.

I want to be able to tell mathematica "see this notebook? assume everything in it is true, dont check it, just believe it." Is there any way to do this? i.e. Is there any way to load the notebook, and just tell mathematica to just treat it as evaluated without actually having mathematica evaluate it?

Comment: Look at documentation for [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html). Note that "Files written by DumpSave cannot be exchanged between operating systems that differ in $SystemWordLength."

Comment: Check out `Iconize`. It can be used to preserve evaluation results between Mathematica sessions.

Comment: Does Iconize only work within one computer? Or can it work across computers?

Comment: Works fine across computers. Try it!